# Is "clasp it there" correctly used here?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure if I am using the sentence correctly. I want to use the word clasp to mean fasten, and it there to mean it's fastened in a particular location.

Here's the sentence I am trying to write:

> He put a bottle of beer under his arm pit and clasped it there with
>   his arm.

It sounds odd, but I believe the sentence is correct. Is it?

Comment: *Armpit* is a word without a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly you can use **clasp** figuratively, as any method of holding something.

Amongst many related meanings, OED has

> **clasp** verb "To take hold of by means of encircling parts; to hold closely by closing round; loosely and poetic to environ, surround, enfold."